# I'm not sure if I understand

Tags: php, arrays, object-properties

I'm not sure if I understand properties() method  right
It's pulling out values from $db_table_fields and making them keys in array $properties and also assigning them as values of the same array...?

don't want just to copy/paste code trying to understand it..

```
class User{

    protected static $db_table = "users";
    protected static $db_table_fields = array('username','password','first_name','last_name');
    public $id;
    public $username;
    public $password;    
    public $first_name;
    public $last_name;

    protected function properties(){
        $properties = array();
        foreach(self::$db_table_fields as $db_field ){
            if(property_exists($this,$db_field)){
                $properties[$db_field] = $this->$db_field;
            }
        }
        return $properties;
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly are you not able to understand.

Comment: Consider the difference between `$db_field` and `$this->$db_field`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's creating an associative array whose elements correspond to selected properties of the object. The array `$db_table_fields` lists those properties. It then loops through that array and checks whether `$this` contains a property with each name. If the property exists, it adds an entry to the `$properties` array whose key is the property name, and whose value is the property value. This is the critical line:

```
$properties[$db_field] = $this->$db_field;
```

`$properties[$db_field] =` means to create an element of the `$properties` array whose key is `$db_field` (the current element of the loop). And `$this->$db_field` uses `$db_field` as a property name to access in the current object.

Answer (score 0):

It's creating what is called an 'associative array'. This means that the array is indexed using a string key instead of a numerical index.

For more information, check out the documentation for Arrays:
[Arrays in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)